# I want to create a script that automatically inputs password to ssh client to do reboot on /etc/rc.local

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, openssh

The code manually is:

```
ssh -fNv -L 3049:localhost:2049 ubuntu@20.115.5.61
```

Now I have in /etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_host=ubuntu@20.115.5.61
remote_port=3049
local_port=2049
cmd="ssh -fN -R ${remote_port}:localhost:${local_port} ${remote_host}"

while true; do
    pgrep -fx "$cmd" >/dev/null 2>&1 || $cmd
    sleep 10
done
```

¿Help me?

Comment: *... password to ssh client ...* You're doing it wrong.  That's why SSH keys exist - so you can do **secure logins** without the need for a password that's usually stored **insecurely**.

Comment: so how can i fix it?

Comment: Setup an SSH key pair for your systems, you find tutorials for this on the web.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.